# Differences in Performance: MediaCodec in Kotlin vs NDK

Tags: android-ndk, h.264, android-mediacodec

Why am I experiencing significant performance differences, with 25fps using the H.264 decoder in MediaCodec NDK and 150fps using the H.264 decoder in MediaCodec Kotlin, when processing the same file?
Resolution: 1280 x 720
Decoder: OMX.sprd.h264.decoder
NDK Version : 21
Android Api: 28
Phone: Wiko Y80

I've tried various approaches without success. Any insights on improving performance would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: This could be a matter of software vs hardware codec instance or a performance bottleneck in your code.